# trouble installing mercurial on mac os x lion

Tags: macos, mercurial

I tried installing graphicsmagick as part of the install instructions for docsplit (http://documentcloud.github.com/docsplit/)

when i say:

```
> brew install --use-gcc --HEAD graphicsmagick
```

i get

```
Error: You must `easy_install mercurial'
```

when i run

```
> sudo easy_install mercurial
```

I get a huge python stacktrace.

you can find that stacktrace here:

```
http://pastebin.com/dwwjEc4j
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.  You appear to have a development version of `setuptools` installed or installed in the past somewhere on the directory search path for the system Python.  Note the `setuptools==0.6c12dev-r85381` in the traceback.  That is not the version supplied by Apple in the final 10.7 release at least.  You should be able to see where it is being imported from by doing this:

```
$ /usr/bin/python2.7
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 16 2011, 16:59:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import setuptools
>>> setuptools.__file__
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/__init__.py'
```

That's what is *should* look like.  If there is a different file, go to the directory it is in (*not* `/System/Library`) and remove the traces of setuptools including `setupttools.pth`.  Most likely you either have a `PYTHONPATH` environment variable defined or you will find the old `setuptools` in `/Library/Python`.